# Start a new instance of an activity from the same activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, instance

I am trying to create a new instance of an activity from within the same class of the activity. For instance I have a Activity called Settings.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this, Settings.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("ShowBookmarks", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in my AndroidManifest I don't have any launch options set, though I have tried with singleTop and a couple others.

The goal is to display different data in the same controls (Recycler view, etc), and then be able to click back to show the previous data.

Comment: Sounds like a xy-problem.... re-think your approach

Comment: @B001ᛦ A little guidance would be helpful. The only other solution I have been able to come up with doesn't give the user flow that I want. That is just to reload the data, but then it won't provide the back icon without having to add it manually, and I would prefer to not do that.

Comment: _A little guidance would be helpful..._ I think @Rohit5k2 said all

Comment: I don't know if this will work. Sounds dangerous (but hey, living on the edge, right?). Why don't you use various instances of a fragment? Or even better, different fragments? If your goal is just to display data, fragments sound good.

Comment: Bad design. Change data not activity. Take Fragment approach.

Comment: My problem is I inherited this project from a very poor developer and I don't have the time to write things in a way to use fragments. I'll see what I can do. Thanks

Comment: Another approach would be to update the views in your activity, and keep the data in arrays or dictionaries (Maps, in Java). Then simply iterate through them as you require.

Comment: Why don't you try using [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) instead? You can learn more about them [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm).

Comment: @LuísHenriques That was the other option I had considered, and I think that is the best option I have in my current timeline/situation.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is your best option as well, given the circunstances. Good luck.

Comment: Please stop voting down this question. Just because you don't agree with the approach, doesn't mean it doesn't belong in Stack Overflow. After all, we are trying to build a hub of knowledge for future use as well. It is good to register that this is not the best approach, and which are the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

> Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this, Settings.class);

**I don't know if that's possible | Re-think your strategy**

***But, if you want to just restart your activity:***

You don't have to write those long things.

Just call `onResume();` from anywhere.

> I do that in this way.

Also,

Since *API level 11*, you can call the `recreate();` method of the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

- Create two Fragments or you can manage using one fragment means go with one fragment.
- Add the fragment into backstack (addToBackStack(String name)) with different name.
- Pop the fragment in onBackPressed() method.

It will work as you expected.

> Note: All your activity related code move into Fragment.